# How to print object list attribute properly based off Google Sheets API?

Tags: python, google-sheets

I am new to Python and inexperienced with using Lists instead of Arrays.  I am trying to specifically print one attribute of an object contained in a list of objects of the same type.

I was reading some differences between **str** and **repr** as **str** was not printing what I wanted.  I read that both should be defined, even if they are exactly the same.  When I am outputting now I am getting the following:

```
<bound method MacAuth.__str__ of XXXXXXXXXXXX>
<bound method MacAuth.__str__ of XXXXXXXXXXXX>
<bound method MacAuth.__str__ of XXXXXXXXXXXX>
```

Where XXXXXXXXXX is actually showing the correct attribute and EXACTLY what I want to see. I don't need the rest of the output line though.

Also, this information was read off of Google Sheets API as a cell.value(), so I'm not sure if that could be causing issues.

```
class MacAuth():

    def __init__(self, mac_address):
        self.mac_address = mac_address
        self.registerd_user = 'registerd_user'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mac_address

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.mac_address

mac_list = list()
for i in range(start, end):
    mac = sheet.cell(i,2).value
    mac_list.append(MacAuth(mac))

for i in range(0,3):
    print(mac_list[i].__str__, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the string value if you `call` the method on print:

```
print(mac_list[i].__str__(), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check in the morning and see what I can come up with

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) for `str()`. The relevant part:

> `str(object)` returns `object.__str__()`, which is the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of object. For string objects, this is the string itself. If object does not have a `__str__()` method, then `str()` falls back to returning `repr(object)`.

Similarly, `repr()` calls `__repr__()`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) on `print()`:

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like `str()` does and written to the stream

So `print(obj)` behaves like `str(obj)`, except that it writes to a stream instead of returning the value. What this means is that your solution ends up being simpler than you thought:

```py
# you can iterate over the list directly
for mac_auth in mac_list:
    # sep='\n' is the default value, so you don't need to specify it 
    print(mac_auth)
```

---

As a side note, the reason you're currently seeing this:

```py
<bound method MacAuth.__str__ of XXXXXXXXXXXX>
```

is because the method `MacAuth.__str__` is also an object, with it's own string representation defined, and `print` converts the method to a string.

The representations of bound methods include a reference to the object they're bound to, in this case a `MacAuth` object. The flow would be similar to this:

1. `print()` tries to convert the method `__str__` (which is an object in itself), bound to a `MacAuth` object, to a string
2. `__str__`'s string representation includes the object it's bound to, something like `<bound method MacAuth.__str__ of [MacAuth obj]>`
3. To print the `[MacAuth obj]` portion, that object's `__str__` is called, which returns the `mac_address` attribute as desired

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.  I will check on this in the morning and see what I can do :)